# Are there established algorithms for working with towers of low-degree algebraic extensions?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction, computational-algebra

I'm interested in doing 'computational ruler-and-compass' construction simulations along the lines of [Euclidea](https://www.euclidea.xyz/) and similar tools. Because the constructions can get rather involved, I'd like to be able to work with exact objects — for instance, in the construction of the 17-gon, this would include the value $\cos(2\pi/17)=\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}$ where $\zeta_{17}=e^{2\pi i/17}$ is the pritive 17th root of unity; this value is constructed via quadratic extensions as part of the solution of the puzzle. Since I'm looking at ruler-and-compass style constructions, my extensions would be relatively low-degree — either degree-2, or maybe degree-3 if I consider doing some origami constructions. At the same time, the algebraic numbers themselves can get complicated — witness the aforementioned $\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}$, which is of degree 8 and is usually built via a tower of three quadratic extensions from $\mathbb{Q}$. Are there any good algorithms for working with algebraic numbers that are in such (smallish) towers of low-degree extensions, particularly for constructing the towers and being able to assert algebraic equality etc.?

Comment: $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{17}):\Bbb Q]=16$ (and not $8$?).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Whoops, good catch — the interesting value there is the real part of $\zeta_{17}$, which _is_ of degree 8. Apologies!

Comment: (Though strictly speaking I suppose $\zeta_{17}$ itself is constructed since the last step there is essentially an intersection of the unit circle with the line $x=\Re(\zeta_{17})$, so there is a fourth extension that happens...)

Comment: Have you tried SageMath or Magma?

Comment: @André3000 Ack. I clearly need more coffee this morning — I'm less interested in existing software than in the algorithms themselves; I was thinking 'tool' in the abstract sense. (And while I know some of the very basics of computational algebraic number theory, working with ideals, Gröbner bases and such, I'm not sure whether there are particular techniques that are applicable to this specific setting.)